# Django date comparison different on server

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have just become aware of some very strange date comparison behaviour on our production setup which I don't understand.

**Listing Model**

```
title (CharField)
from_date (DateTimeField)
to_date (DateTimeField)
```

**QuerySet**

```
now = arrow.now()
Listing.objects.filter(to_date__gte=now.datetime)
```

**Setup**

- Python 2.7
- Django 1.7
- SQLite / PostgreSQL
- Ubuntu

**Issue**

When a listing object's to_date is set to an hour earlier than now, both on the development server and the shell on the production server, the query set returns the correct results (the listing in question is not included). However, on the production server, the query continues to include the listing (no caching is enabled). I have determined that if I set the listing's day to the previous day it is then properly excluded making it seem that only days are being compared (I even set the time to 00:00 to rule out timezone issues, but this still included the listing - as noted, only changing the day worked). Why is this happening please and how can I fix it?

**Additional Info**

1. I have used the "date" command to confirm the server timezone agrees with the timezone specified in settings.py
2. I have confirmed that `USE_TZ = True` in settings.py and that TIME_ZONE has been properly set.
3. I have logged onto the PostgreSQL terminal on the server and ran the `now` command - this returned the same timezone as both that of the system and that specified in settings.py
4. I have confirmed the to_date field in postgresql is a "timestamp with time zone field"
5. Extract of actual sql passed to db:`WHERE ( "directory_listing"."to_date" >= 2015-08-22 14:01:56.663072)`

Comment: Is the time correct on the systems? check with the 'date' command.

Comment: @ChrisMontanaro Yes, I did check the date and it is correct to the minute. I also ran the query on the shell on the server where it returns the correct results

Comment: You can check/compare the sql actually thrown against the database with: print Listing.objects.filter(to_date__gte=now.datetime).query That should give you an idea about what is going on.

Comment: Thanks - did that - it is using the expected date. In any event, the query has always returned the correct results in the shell

Comment: If both queries are the same, than peek into the (postgres?) query log.
You should see full UTC (or another timezone) dates there.
Double check your USE_TZ and TIME_ZONE in your projects setting.py.
Or: Show your requests timezone in a view: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/#get-current-timezone

Comment: As said above:
1) Look into the query log of the database and compare the datetimes used.
2) Print the timezone, so you are 100% sure django is using your settings.
And it would be a good idea to show the definition of "arrow" here, so people know, what kind of object that is, and what now() returns.

Comment: Is pytz installed on the production server? Also, what timezone are you using?

Comment: @PeterMalmgren Yes, Pytz 2015.4 is installed. Timezone is Europe/London

Comment: Are you able to add the actual SQL which is being sent to the server to your question? Also, log into the database using psql command and run `\d {tablename}` to let us see how the table is defined in the database.

Comment: I notice you have listed 'SQLite/Postgresql' under setup. What role is SQLite playing in this?

Comment: @harmic sqlite is the dev db and postgresql the production db

Comment: @harmic the field's type is "timstamp with time zone"

Comment: @harmic please see updates to my question for actual sql etc

Comment: is there any reason not to use `django.utils.timezone.now()` instead of `arrow.now().datetime`?

Comment: different db connections may use different connections settings including the timezone settings. Also, check how the default value for `to_date` is set

Answer (score 1):

I believe the key to the discrepancy you are seeing is that you are using two different database engines, one in your development environment and another in your production environment, and they have very different handling of dates and times.

[SQLite does not have a specific date/time data type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Dates and times can be stored in textual format, floating point quantities, or integers, and various functions are used to convert the input data into one of these forms for storage or comparison purpose. Also it does not have any specific 'datetime with timezone' data type, or even full support for timezone conversions between arbitrary timezones.

[Postgresql has comprehensive support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) for dates, times, intervals and timestamps with and without timezones. It also has operators specifically defined for comparing these with each other.

I suspect that Django is using the text form when using SQLite as a database backend. If that is the case then given a WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE (to_date >= '2015-08-22 14:01:56.663072')
```

it would be using a plain textual comparison - which would appear to work OK since you can compare two ISO8601 strings that way (*as long as you don't care about time zones*).

In your production environment you are using postgresql, with a 'timestamp with time zone' type. This means that the data stored in the database is stored with time zone information attached.

In this scenario there several time zones at play:

- The timezone of your Django / python environment
- The system timezone on the machine that is running the client (Django) software
- The time zone of your database (configured via the [timezone](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) configuration parameter, which you can check using the command `SHOW timezone;` at the psql prompt).
- Whatever time zone information is embedded in strings sent to and fro the database.

According to your comments you have checked at least some of these settings.

One possibility is that when the records were inserted into the database, the `to_date` field included a timezone and it was not the same as the one that the postgresql database is set to use. For example consider this:

```
ispdb_t2=> select '2015-08-22 00:00:00-10:00'::timestamp with time zone >= '2015-08-22 14:01:56.663072';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

It looks as if it thinks that `2015-08-22 00:00:00` is >= `2015-08-22 14:01:56.663072`. What is actually happening here is that the timestamp on the left has the time zone -10, while the timestamp on the right does not have any timezone appended, so it is interpreted in the timezone of the database session (which in my case is 'Australia/Victoria', currently UTC+10 hours).

To verify if this is a factor in your case I would suggest the following steps:

1. Verify the value of the 'timezone' postgresql configuration parameter. Note that it is settable per session - so you should also confirm if the Django framework is sending a `SET timezone` command after connecting
2. Check the SQL being used to insert values in the database. Confirm if the time values do or do not include embedded time zones.
3. Confirm the values of literals being sent within queries, for example within WHERE clauses. Confirm if they do or do not contain embedded time zones (does not look like they do, from the information you have presented).
4. Obtain the **exact** text of SQL being executed by the server, including any placeholder values. Attempt to run the same queries directly in the database using the psql command line tool. When doing so, ensure you set the `timezone` to the same value as Django is doing (if any). You can then experiment with changing various values until you get a working query, and work backward from there to get your Django code working.

TIP: You can get postgresql to log all statements by setting the configuration parameter `log_statement` to `all`.

You probably do not want to be doing this kind of testing on your actual production system. I recommend you alter the configuration of your dev system so that it is using Postgresql as it's backend, and then reproduce the problem you are experiencing there.

That brings me to my final advice: **whenever possible use the same database system in your development system as you are using in production**. Even allowing for frameworks that are supposed to hide the details of the database from the application developer, there are often large differences between the way different SQL databases operate.

Comment: I have awarded the bounty to you as it expires today and you have provided the clearest, most comprehensive answer. I will do all checks and tests you recommended over the next few days and if it solves my problem, I will mark your answer as accepted. Kudos on your tip re not having different dbs for dev/prod - a mistake I wont make again.

Comment: Referring to your point 2 above - should items being inserted have timezones or not? My understanding is they should but your statement in point 3 makes it seem they should not. btw my USE_TZ param in python is True

Comment: @RunLoop it depends on what you are doing with the timestamps. If your application should handle timestamps that originate in different timezones, and be able to compare them, then you should use a data type that respects timezones, and include the timezone in input data (including any where clauses). However you need to be consistent! Re: point 3, I meant that the WHERE clause in your question did not include a time zone so I assume your application is not including them. Sorry that bit was poorly worded.

Comment: after spending several more hours testing locally and on dev, logging the raw sql, do shell tests, etc. to no avail, I finally restarted gunicorn and the correct results are being returned. Seems either django or postgresql is doing some cahcing (although I have not enabled any)

Answer (score 0):

arrow.now().datetime adds some tzdata. My thought is that you have a different timezone set in your different envs.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 11, 31, 39, 443054)
>>> arrow.now().datetime
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 11, 31, 39, 445013, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```

reconfigure your timezone in Ubuntu with:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

also check your [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE) settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have checked that the timezone on the server and the timezone in settings.py are the same. And as I noted running the test in the shell on the server gives the correct results, which seems to me to confirm that the timezone settings match. However, to double check I set the time component of the to_date to 00:00 to avoid timezone differences, but this still had no effect. Only by changing the day does the query return the correct results

Comment: It only makes sense to make if the dates are being compared as strings rather than actual datetime objects.  It happened to me once, the date field in sqlite was a text field -- can you paste the output of the commands for listing column data types here?

Comment: Yo got a undefined timestamp. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: @chromano I have confirmed it is an "timestamp with time zone" field